# How to make circular progress with point inside SwiftUI ? (Widgets accessoryCircular)

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

Apple has introduced new LockScreen widgets, in which, as an example, they have made a progress widget with a point around which there is a void

How can I make such a void effect on SwiftUI ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a "void"? You mean the text "22"?

Comment: That's a [Gauge](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gauge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SwiftUI's `Gauge` with `.gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircular)`. Here's an example from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gauge):

```
struct LabeledGauge: View {

    @State private var current = 67.0
    @State private var minValue = 0.0
    @State private var maxValue = 170.0

    var body: some View {
        Gauge(value: current, in: minValue...maxValue) {
            Text("BPM")
        } currentValueLabel: {
            Text("\(Int(current))")
        } minimumValueLabel: {
            Text("\(Int(minValue))")
        } maximumValueLabel: {
            Text("\(Int(maxValue))")
        }
        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircular)
    }
}
```

[image]